# In word2vec, for analogies do we use "in" or "out" vectors?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, word2vec, word-embeddings

In **word2vec** each word is associated with two vectors (one for *in* and one for *out*) so that it predicts conditional probability:

$$P(word_{out}|word_{in}) = \frac{\exp(v_{in} \cdot \tilde{v}_{out})}{\sum_k \exp(v_{in} \cdot \tilde{v}_{k})}$$

But which one of the vectors ($v_{in}$ or $\tilde{v}_{out}$) is used for analogies (e.g. the famous `man - king = woman - queen`)?

See:

[image]

from [Christopher Moody, word2vec, LDA, and introducing a new hybrid algorithm: lda2vec](http://www.slideshare.net/ChristopherMoody3/word2vec-lda-and-introducing-a-new-hybrid-algorithm-lda2vec) slides.

EDIT:

The question is on word2vec, not on the slides.

Comment: Some hints: Word2vec is not a single algorithm. So is Moody referring to the Skip-Gram or CBOW model? How are v_in and v_out generated (i.e., from what data are they estimated) for that model? What is the purpose of the the softmax function you show, where is it used (hint: in the objective function)? Last and strongest hint: In your binary question, the answer is the one you did not list... ;-)

Comment: @fnl These "hints" are not helpful. It is not a homework, and I already asked a number of people doing ML (getting all "I don't know" answers). I know that word2vec is a collection of algorithms, so I try to make sense out of it. In particular, I wrote an expression to pinpoint a particular model. Cost function - I guess log-loss. Yes, I know about windowing (i.e. looking at words not further than some fixed $d$). If the answer is different than ones I listed, I would be especially interested to learn about it.

Comment: Sigh, I wasted my time with the quoted slide show, but it is incomprehensible without the speaker explicating the slides.

Comment: You really should at least try to answer some of the questions I asked first. And you might imagine there could be a good reason why your question isn't getting any votes despite the "hot" topic. Finally, you obviously don't understand the topic (yet), and therefore I don't think that "just telling" you the answer would help you in any meaningful way. However, while links don't count as proper answers - your answer is found within any good neural word embedding tutorial, for example here: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/word2vec/index.html

Comment: @fnl New to Stack Exchange? Good. So: 1. It is not a forum. (Comments are for clarification, not cat and mouse games.) 2. Don't assume that I know nothing. Of course if I knew EVERYTHING (as you do), I wouldn't need to ask a single question. 3. Actually, I read gensim's intro, http://www-personal.umich.edu/~ronxin/pdf/w2vexp.pdf (CBOW vs skip-gram) and http://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.3722v1.pdf (on why skip-gram is related to SVD) and still don't get it (not "just saw some cool slides"). 4. Thanks for the TensorFlow link - I find their tutorials clear and will look at it!

Comment: You surely know the phrase "Give a man fish, ..." Also, I already told you the answer to your question, which is "none of the two", quite literally. After reading the tutorial, however, you should know the answer you probably are seeking and, more importantly, have gained a solid understanding of this technique. To explain you what V_in and _out are: Input and output (vector) here refers to the conditioning event and the event (word) for which we wish to estimate a conditional probability, not to input and output of the dual-layer perceptron. Bad naming policy? Yes, I would certainly say so.

Comment: @fnl There (TensorFlow tutorial on word2vec) are hints suggesting the usage of "in" vectors, by using "embedding" space for the values on the hidden layer. But since "encoding" (input to hidden) and "decoding" (hidden to output) vectors are different, it's still not obvious why "encoding" vectors are better than "decoding"? (An empirical fact? There is no difference so pick any? Some theoretical justification?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see it's typically left vectors.

Most of techniques base on decomposition of a symmetric matrix (either PPMI as for Skip-Gram Negative-Sampling or co-occurrence probability as for GloVe and Skip-Gram Noise Contrastive Estimation). Yet, due to non-uniform sampling of the context vectors (some sublinear) and numerical algorithms, the left and right vectors are different.

See e.g. here:

[image]

- [Semantics with Dense Vectors (Chapter 16)](https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/16.pdf) from [Speech and Language Processing (3rd ed. draft) by Dan Jurafsky and James H. Martin](https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/).

Answer (score 2):

Garten et al. (1) compared word vectors obtained by *adding* input word vectors with output word vectors, vs. word vectors obtained by *concatenating* input word vectors with output word vectors. In their experiments, concatenating yield significantly better results:

[image]

---

(1) Garten, J., Sagae, K., Ustun, V., & Dehghani, M. (2015, June). [Combining Distributed Vector Representations for Words](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=Combining+Distributed+Vector+Representations+for+Words&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C22). In Proceedings of NAACL-HLT (pp. 95-101).

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, irrespective of what architecture is used (skip-gram/CBOW), word vectors are read from same word-vector matrix.

As suggested in second footnote of the [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.3722v1.pdf), $v_{in}$ and $\tilde{v}_{out}$ of same word (say $dog$) should be different, and they are assumed to be coming from different vocabularies during the derivation of the loss function.

Practically, probability of  word appearing in its own context is very low, and most implementations don't save two vector representations of same word for saving memory and efficiency.